# Не понимаю битовые операции Python & |

Tags: python, битовые-операции

Не понимаю, что, собственно, делает с числом такие **битовые операции** как **&** и **|**

`5 & 3` даёт `1`, а `5 | 3` даёт `7`. Я думал, что оно выбирает наименьшее\наибольшее соответственно и отнимает\добавляет разницу. Но `8 & 5` выводит `0`, а не `3`, по моим догадкам; `3 | 6` выводит `7`, а не `9`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. В интернете читал - сложно  и запутанно. Если на вопрос о **битовом НЕ ~** я получил ответ, что

> Побитовая операция НЕ для числа x соответствует `-(x+1)` так, что `~5`
>   даёт `-6`.

и здесь всё сразу понятно, то на **битовые И** и **ИЛИ** чёткого ответа простыми словами нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для разницы есть операция вычитания :) Вам не мешало бы для начала разобраться что такое биты. Прочитайте немного про двоичную систему.

Если в двух словах по вашим во просам.
`5` представляем как `101`  а `3` как `011` (тут речь идет о представлении десятичных чисел в двоичной системе исчисления) побитовое `и`  оставляет единицу только когда  оба значения в соответственном разряде - единицы

```
101
&
011
___
001
```

Как видите здесь единица остается там, где две единицы в двух сравниваемых числах (представлены в двоичной системе исчисления)

Второй пример рассмотрим тоже. `|` - побитовое `или` . "Оставляет" единицы когда какой либо из соответствующих разрядов чисел является единицей. Т.е.

```
101
|
011
___
111
```

А `111` это и есть `7` в десятичной системе.

Вот собственно и все.

Вот прям на вскидку вам для почитать про битовые операции
https://server.179.ru/tasks/python/2014b1/22-bits.html - первая ссылка в гугле.
Вот тут еще достойно описано 
https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Ну и да, зачем это вам может пригодится? Ну это совсем другой вопрос :)

Answer (score 3):

Это довольно просто.

Битовое "И" — это операция над двумя битами, которая даёт на выходе единицу, когда И тот, И другой её аргументы равны единице: 1 & 1 = 1, 1 & 0 = 0, 0 & 1 = 0, 0 & 0 = 0.

Битовое "ИЛИ" — это операция над двумя битами, которая даёт на выходе единицу, когда тот ИЛИ иной её аргумент равен единице. Если оба — тоже: 1 & 1 = 1, 1 & 0 = 1, 0 & 1 = 1, 0 & 0 = 0.

А теперь смотрите, как выполняется, например, побитовое "И" для чисел 5 и 8.
Сначала запишем их в двоичной форме (нам хватит одного байта для каждого):

00000101

и

00001000

а теперь проведём операцию "И" как она описана выше побитово над соответствующими битами и запишем результат:

00000000, так как в единицу взвелись только те биты, которые установлены в единицу в КАЖДОМ из аргументов.

Результат же операции "ИЛИ" будет 00001101, так как в единицу взводятся биты, установленные в единицу в ЛЮБОМ из аргументов.

Операция XOR, кстати, подобна "ИЛИ", но взводит в единицу те биты, у которых операнды РАЗЛИЧАЮТСЯ.

А, да. Стандартное применение битовых "И" и "ИЛИ" — проверка/сброс и установка битовых полей соответственно. Я напишу в сишной нотации, поймёте?

```
unsigned char bitfield = 0x0a; // decimal 10, binary 00001010
...
bitfield = bitfield | 0x01;// устанавливаем самый правый бит в единицу
if (bitfield & 0x02) {     // проверяем, взведён ли второй справа бит.
...                        // внутренняя логика этой операции проста: в скобках получится не-ноль 
                           // (то есть "истина" в понимании Си) только если в переменной bitfield 
}                          // *тоже* взведён второй бит (остальные на результат не влияют,
                           // т.к. при битовом "И" с 00000010 всё равно обращаются в ноль)
bitfield = bitfield & 0xfe;// сбрасываем самый правый бит в ноль, не трогая 
                           // остальные (0xfe - это 11111110)
```